# How does *node copy *next?

Tags: c++, pointers, linked-list

I understand how linked lists work but this particular code is tough to grasp for me.

Its [this](https://leetcode.com/problems/delete-node-in-a-linked-list/) leetcode problem (basically we are given address of a node which is to be deleted) whose solution can be implemented like the code snippet below:

```
1. class Solution {
2. public:
3.     void deleteNode(ListNode* node) {       
4.         ListNode* next = node->next;
5.         *node = *next;
6.         delete next;
7.     }
8. };
```

I know that:

1. `&node` would mean the address of node variable
2. `node` means the value (information) stored at address called node
3. `*node` is used to dereference the pointer variable called node.

My doubt:

1. [IMP] If we need to dereference a `node` pointer to get its data (like in line 5), then why not do so while accessing its member elements too (in line 4 `node->next`)?
2. [Not IMP] Then, how does `*node` copies `*next`'s data?

Comment: Please don't go to such so-called "competition" or "online judge" sites to learn programming or programming languages. That's not what they're for. If you want to learn C++ invest in [some good books](https://stackoverflow.com/a/388282/440558) and take proper classes. You should stay as far away from such sites as possible while learning.

Comment: _What does *node mean?_ That depends on the context. `ListNode* node` is a declaration of a function parameter. The `*` denotes a pointer type. `*node = *next;` is an expression. Now, `*` is the [indirection operator](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_member_access) (can be imagined as a kind of "contents-of-pointer operator"). `node` and `next` are pointers. `*next` delivers the contents of `next`. Actually, the returned type is a reference (or const reference). Hence, `*node` on the left hand side works as well. It provides the reference where to assign the `*next` into.

Comment: This pointer syntax is inherited from C. K&R did this intentionally. I remember having read they considered it as nice that the `*` may appear at the same position in declaration and expressions. They probably overlooked (or ignored) the fact that learners  may be simply not aware of that the `*` has nevertheless different meanings. (Not to mention, that there is also a binary operator * for multiply - as usual in other languages as well.)

Comment: @Scheff'sCat thanks for explaining. I just forgot to mention that I knew the indirection/dereference operator. I was actually confused about my doubt no. 1 (pls check the edited question)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`node->next` is actually equivalent to `(*node).next`. So there's an implicit dereference there already.

As for the copying, I assume you understand assignment between e.g. plain `int` variables? As in:

```
int a = 5;
int b = 10;

a = b;
```

It's quite natural that the value of `b` will be copied into `a`.

Now lets do the same again, but with one pointer to `b`:

```
int a = 5;
int b = 10;

int* pb = &b;  // pb is pointing to b

a = *pb;
```

This is really doing exactly the same as `a = b`.

And another example with a pointer to `a` instead:

```
int a = 5;
int b = 10;

int* pa = &a;  // pa is pointing to a

*pa = b;
```

Again this is the same as `a = b`.

Now putting them together:

```
int a = 5;
int b = 10;

int* pa = &a;  // pa is pointing to a
int* pb = &b;  // pb is pointing to b

*pa = *pb;
```

It's still the same as `a = b`.

It doesn't really matter if the pointers are to plain `int` variables or values, or to structures, it works the same for all pointers.

Comment: Your answer's first line led me to [this](https://www.usna.edu/Users/cs/wcbrown/courses/F14IC210/lec/l34/lec.html) and cleared my doubts

Answer (score 0):

`*node` is the entity of the passed-in parameter, including the node value and the next address. `*node = *next` is a shallow copy. If the ListNode is complex, the shallow copy may cause some problems. Deep copy is recommended.
`ListNode` is here:

```
struct ListNode {
    int val;
    ListNode *next;
    ListNode(int x) : val(x), next(NULL) {}
};
```

This way is better to understand:

```
class Solution {
public:
    void deleteNode(ListNode* node) {
        ListNode* next = node->next;
        node->val = next->val;
        node->next = next->next;
        delete next;
    }
};
```

Comment: Is this how to do deep copy?
node->next = node->next->next;
node->data = node->next->data;

Comment: Yes, I think so.

Comment: `*node = *next` is not a shallow copy, it's outright invalid code.  `node = next` would be a shallow copy.